# Navigation Drawer Activity cannot find symbol from Resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So I'm trying to create Navigation Drawer to my app, according to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks) tutorial, and all the resources that I'm trying to assign, that according to the guide supposed to be already implemented in the Android Studio, just doesn't appear in the code-completing.

here is a piece of code that I can't auto complete with my resources, by the way, I downloaded the whole code and searched in their layouts, but didn't find something.

in this method, the action_websearch cannot be found:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: do you want to get the image from the drawable folder dynamically?

Comment: @vspallas I dont understand why I don't own it in the first place, it seems like its something that should be build in the system

Answer (score 0):

That id is of the menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
          android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_websearch"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

You can find it in res/menu folder.

Make sure you have no errors in the menu layout.

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: open it and see if all the resources refered there are available... See also all layouts, errors in layouts can make R not to work as it should. In this case could be bloking from finding this id...

Comment: I asked because i don't see menu folder in my project. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: I just downloaded the sample as you said, the menu folder is inside the res folder and has that main.xml file for the menu. You must have that or implement your own and change that id for yours.

Comment: I meant in my project.

Comment: in my project, I copied the menu folder but now i need to copy the icons and the title as well because it yells at me.

Comment: you can just change them for others in your project... But if you plan on using what comes default in the samples, yes, you have to import all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want I can share a Code source that you can modify!

Because I can write you some help but maybe you will get more confused!

[Example DRAWER](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i3fyiqmh0brl7b3/AACLoLXDyacMijjLi3zM5tjka?dl=0)

//**MAINACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Configuracion de las referencias de cada uno de los elementos
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        title = getTitle().toString();

        //Llamada al metodo configs
        configs();

        //Configuracion de el boton por default para llamar el drawer en el ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void configs() {
        //Creacion y configuracion de la lista para el drawer
        String[] array = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Configuracion del listener de los elementos de la lista
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Referencia y creacion del drawerToogle pasando como referencia el layout y los strings
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            //Metodo llamado cuadno se abre el drawer
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Open!");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }
        };

        //Configuracion del listener para habilitar el drawer
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    //Actualiza el estado del navigation drawer
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    //Mantiene el estado del navigation drawer durante una configuracion de la actividad (Voltear el telefono)
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        //Activa el toogle del navigation drawer
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//***layout.xml:***

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @cpburnz Thanks for your suggestion :D